# Click Event not firing in Wijmo FlexSheet freeze cells in Firefox & IE

Tags: wijmo, wijmo5

Here [in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L253599m/1/)`

## FlexSheet

```
</p>
<wj-flex-sheet initialized="initialized(s)" item-formatter="itemFormatter">
  <wj-sheet name="Country" items-source="ctx.data"></wj-sheet>
  <wj-sheet name="Empty Sheet"></wj-sheet>
</wj-flex-sheet>
```

` there are two buttons. One placed in a freeze cell and the others is in normal cell. When you click on the freeze cell button it doesn't work in Firefox and IE. But the other buttons does work. I can't figure out any work around.

Answer (score 1):

Setting [CloneFrozenCells](http://demos.wijmo.com/5/Angular/WijmoHelp/WijmoHelp/topic/wijmo.grid.FlexGrid.Class.html#cloneFrozenCells) to false resolves this. [Update Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L253599m/8/)

```
$scope.initialized = function (s) {
    ...
    s.cloneFrozenCells = false;
};
```

If you set the cloneFrozenCells property to false, scrolling frozem cells will cause flicker on all browsers except Chrome (which is really fast).

If you set it to null (the default), the grid will try to guess whether it should be set to true of false. I believe it was not doing this correctly for Safari on the Mac. This has now been fixed in the latest build (482)

PS:
This is valid for FlexGrid and FlexSheet

Comment: Are you sure about it? because here in my case in the jSFiddle `s.cloneFrozenCells = false;` works.

Comment: On a FireFox browser?

Comment: Yes. On FireFox browser (Latest Version). `s.cloneFrozenCells = false;` works. But `s.cloneFrozenCells = true;` doesn't.

Comment: You are right, setting false does this. Thanks for the catch, I have updated the answer.